# JavaScript basico - problemas con el for

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

No entiendo porque el siguiente código me retorna false, debería ser true

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let elemento = 5

  
  for (var i=0; i<array.lenght; i++){
    if (array[i] == elemento);
  window.alert (true);
  }
  window.alert (false);
```

Comment: Fijate que el false lo va a sacar siempre, no depende del resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Este código tiene unos cuantos errores.

`let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let elemento = 5`

A estas dos líneas les falta el `;` final. Y personalmente usaría `var` en vez de `let`, ya que no son variables que se limiten en un bloque de código (como un bucle).

`for (var i=0; i<array.lenght; i++){
if (array[i] == elemento);
window.alert (true);
}`

En el bucle, la propiedad `length` está mal escrita.
Después del `if` no usas `{}`, así que en caso de aplicarse el condicional, va a ejecutar solo la primera instrucción que le siga, y como has puesto un `;`, la instrucción que va a ejecutar es: *ninguna*.
De manera que va a ejecutar un `window.alert (true);` por cada iteración del bucle. Pero no se muestran porque solo va a usar el último `alert`, el `console.log('false');` que hay después del bucle, que se va a ejecutar siempre.
Y por eso siempre muestra un "*false*" (si con el código actual arreglarlo, en vez de alertas, usas mensajes de *log*, mostrará 5 trues y un false)
Por ejemplo:

```js
// Sigue estando mal.
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let elemento = 5;

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  if (array[i] == elemento);
  console.log (true);
}
console.log (false);
```

**Para solucionarlo**, espera a que termine el bucle para saber si ha encontrado algo o no, y para saberlo, puedes usar una variable de control, por ejemplo `var encontrado` que al salir del bucle indique si ha encontrado algo o no, y actuar en consecuencia.
Ya de paso, puedes decirle al bucle, que ya puede salir en caso de encontrarlo.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var elemento = 5;
var encontrado = false;
  
for (var i=0; i<array.length && !encontrado; i++)
  encontrado =array[i] == elemento;
/*
  El bucle iterará mientras 'i' no llegue al final del array y no
  haya encontrado el valor buscado, ya que si lo encuentra, no hace
  falta seguir buscando.
  Como no he usado {} en el for, solo ejecutará en bucle
  el primer comando.
  Como me interesa usar la variable 'i' fuera del bucle, para
  conocer la pocicion del valor encontrado, lo inicializo con un
  'var' en vez de un 'let'
*/

if (encontrado)  window.alert ("Encontrado un "+elemento+" en la posicion "+i);
else window.alert (false);
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, muy bien explicada.

Answer (score 0):

lo primero que observo es que escribiste mal length

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let elemento = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == elemento) {
        console.log('true');
    }
}
console.log('false');
```

Comment: Este código mostrará un 'true' por cada coincidencia, y un 'false' al final.